# Drawing line between two drawables in the textviews

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, android-canvas

[image]

I have the issue with drawing line like in a pic above. How can I do that? Here's the code of the view, where I need to implement that. I guess I need to use canvas, but I'm not sure about that. Thanks for any advice!

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/linear_layout_buttons_margin_top"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/button_from_city"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_white"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_green"
            android:drawablePadding="@dimen/dots_white_button_padding"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_green"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:hint="@string/from_place"
            android:padding="@dimen/dots_white_button_padding"
            android:textColor="@color/color_accent"
            android:textColorHint="@color/text_view_hint_color"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/button_to_city"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/button_from_city"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_white"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_red"
            android:drawablePadding="@dimen/dots_white_button_padding"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_red"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:hint="@string/to_place"
            android:padding="@dimen/dots_white_button_padding"
            android:textColor="@color/color_accent"
            android:textColorHint="@color/text_view_hint_color"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can provide two drawable resources for the textviews and set them as drawableStart, based on the required conditions of your work. The point here is using an image which contains a colored circle and a line, which is much simpler than drawing the layout with canvas.

Answer (score 0):

I will simply add two View with grey background of 1dp width  above and below your dot drawable and manage visibility depending on the position of your items.